# How do I render a page after MongoDB findOne and save (async)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

My question involves the following code:

```
DB.findOne({ '_id' : req.user._id }, function(err, user) {
  user.count+=1;
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) req.flash('error', err.message);
    done(err, user);
    req.flash('success', 'count incremented');
    res.render('page1', {
      user : req.user
      success: req.flash('success'),
    });
  });
});
```

I'm having issues rendering the page after the Mongo query and save are completed.

Is there an elegant solution to this?

Comment: And look at what you chose for a username and yet you cannot work out what you are doing wrong here. Really? Also. Bad pattern. Better: `DB.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id,{ "$inc": { "count": 1 }},{ "new": true },function(err,user) { // work with modified user })`

Comment: New mongoose version uses promises, I would recommend using that. Could save you from Callback H

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the `rend` function inside the **callback**.

```
DB.findOne({ '_id' : req.user._id }, function(err, user) {
  user.count+=1;
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) req.flash('error', err.message);
    done(err, user);
req.flash('success', 'count incremented');
res.render('page1', {
  user : user
  success: req.flash('success'),
});
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

I've tried that but I get `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent` when I do that.

Comment: Have tried, same error but this time, page doesn't render at all.